# M-matrix check in Matlab/Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there a simple way to check that matrix is M-matrix in Octave/Matlab?

Thanks,
Vojta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this works:

```
% A is our matrix
[n,m] = size(A);
if (any(eig(A)) <= 0)
    % Then A is not an M-matrix
    break;
else
    idx = find(A > 0);
    [I,J] = ind2sub([n,m],idx);
    % I and J are the row/col subscript indices for positive entries.
    % We should only have this when i = j. If i =/= j, then i-j =/= 0,
    % so we look for non-zero entries in I-J
    if (any(I-J) ~= 0)
        % Then A is not an M-matrix
        break;
    else
        disp 'M-matrix!';
    end
end
```

Comment: Of course, this calls `eig`, which you may not want to do. In that case you might have to code for other sufficient conditions.

Comment: `if (any(eig(A) <= 0))` was intended, right? And similarly for the second test.